Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile - Try to create a button to change the page when I make more than 1 pages in the App()
Here is my App.kt looked like:
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    val pageShowHome        by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true   ) }
    val pageShowPreference  by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false  ) }

    MaterialTheme {
        Column(Modifier.dapStyleContainer(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            AnimatedVisibility(pageShowHome) {
                Home() // in pages/Home.kt
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(pageShowPreference) {
                Preference() // in pages/Preference.kt
            }
        }
    }
}

And I make a button for my Home display in home/ButtonPreference.kt like this:
@OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
@Composable
fun buttonPreference() {
    Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp), elevation = 8.dp, modifier = Modifier.dapStyleCard().clickable{
        // This one is not working
        pageShowPreference = true
        pageShowHome = false
    }) {
        Row( modifier = Modifier.dapStyleCardRow() ) {
            Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.75f)) {
                Text(text = "Preference", textAlign = TextAlign.Start)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
            }
            Image(painterResource(Res.drawable.icon_cog_dark), contentDescription = "Icon")
        }
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
}

I want something like this code below can change pageShowHome and pageShowPreference value in App.kt.
pageShowPreference = true
pageShowHome = false

The code above is in the home/ButtonPreference.kt. I use buttonPreference() in the pages/Home.kt fun Home() like this code below:
@Composable
fun Home(){
    Header()
    ButtonList()
    ButtonPreference()
}

What must I use to change pageShowHome and pageShowPreference value?
